# nginx,uwsgi - load on startup

Tags: django, linux, nginx, uwsgi

I wanted to execute a ini file on startup. So I created a  file  `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` with

```
# simple uWSGI script

description "uwsgi tiny instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

exec uwsgi --ini /home/iiits/Mahimusic/mahimusic.ini
```

But this did not execute when I rebooted the system.Can I know why?

Comment: which linux distribution are you using and version?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS